# Flash CS6 AS2 Get contents of a URL GET Request

Tags: flash, url, get, actionscript-2

I'm trying to send a GET request in Flash AS2 but can't seem to find any info on how to return the contents of the URL.

The URL will return plain text without any HTML tags, so the HTML code of the URL will just look like plain text `Plain text like this`. And I would like this returned as a String.

So something like: http://www.example.com/?name=John&age=19 would return `Submitted`.

I need the string to use as a conditional statement in AS2, something like:

```
if(returnedVal == "Submitted"){
 nextFrame();
} else {
 error_message._visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var foo:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

foo.onData = function(value:String) {
    if (value != undefined) {
        trace(value);
    }
};

foo.name = "John";
foo.age = 19;
foo.sendAndLoad("content.txt", foo, "GET");
```